# cannot access the POST form data sent by HTML/Javascript code at node js code

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I made a simple nodejs server which serves a html page to the user.The page contains a input text box of userID. When the user presses the button submit, I take that userID entered by the user and put it in form Data and send it to my server function (submitForTest) through POST method.

Now, inside my function of nodejs which handles submitForTest, I tried to access the userID , but I was getting  res.body as {} , so not able to figure out how to access userID here.

Can anyone please point what I need to get the userID at my node js code.

My HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
   <label>User ID</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="userid" >
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" onclick="submitForTest()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function submitForTest()
        {
            var userID = document.getElementById('userid').value;
      let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("userID", userID);

        //alert("hello");
            fetch('http://MY-SERVER:3000/submitForTest', {method: "POST", body: formData});
        }

        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Node js file :

```
'use strict'
const fs = require("fs")
const express = require('express')
var path = require('path')

const app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.get('/',function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile('small.html');
});

app.post('/submitForTest', function(req, res) {
//want to print userID here .. but the below is coming as {} here ..
 console.log(req.body);

})

// Tell our app to listen on port 3000
app.listen(3000, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
}
  console.log('Server started on port 3000')
})
```

Please help.

Regards

Comment: Did you try - app.post('/submitForTest', function(req, res) =>  { ? Pass the result to an anonymous function.

Comment: sorry could not follow your comment, can you please give more details.. Iam very new to node js programming

Comment: Try adding => between (req,res) and the brackets. Looks like an input function rather than result handler

Comment: router.get('/handle',(request,response) => {
    //code to perform particular action.
    //To access GET variable use req.query() and req.params() methods.
});

Comment: still getting {} : app.post('/submitForTest', (req, res) =>  {
 console.log(req.body);
 console.log(req.params);

})

Comment: log console.log(JSON.stringify(res))

Comment: Sorry - you are trying to check the parameters being passed to the service  - so req

Comment: getting this error :  TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: still same error on using req

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `FormData` is sending body encoded as [`multipart/form-data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). You'll have to add middleware able to handle `multipart` body format. [Busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy#readme) or [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme) for example.

Example of using `multer` to upload a file and send `userID` field:

```html
// --- form
<form action="/submitForTest" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
    <input type="text" name="userID">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">            
</form>
```

```ts
// --- server
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads/' }) // where the uploaded files will be stored
app.post('/submitForTest', upload.single('uploaded_file'), function (req, res) {
   // req.file is the name of your file in the form above, here 'uploaded_file'
   // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any 
   console.log(req.file, req.body)
});
```

Or to send your data in `urlencoded` or `json` format. Something like that for `json` for example:

```ts
function submitForTest()
{
    var userID = document.getElementById('userid').value;
    fetch('http://MY-SERVER:3000/submitForTest', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ userID }),
    });
}
```

Comment: can you please give example of multer usage which can fix this issue ?

Comment: or please tell me how to send my  data in json format ?

Comment: I'd assume if you're not sending binary data to the server to use `json`. That's way easier.

Comment: actually I will  be sending some more things in the form as well . like some more text fields and some objects as well ( objects which gets passed through upload file window box) .  So can you please tell how to give that in your answer provided ?

Comment: Well, for binary data (as files) you're better off using `FormData` object. Then just add one of the `multipart` body parsers to middlware chain.

Comment: then in that case, can you please give example of multer usage which can fix this issue ? actually iam very new to node js programming

Comment: for your simple json solution , how to pass 2 text strings : support userID, and name ? Below code is not working : fetch('http://MY_SERVER:3000/submitForTest', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ userID }, { name } ),
});

Comment: `JSON.stringify` accepts a _single_  javascript object and converts it into a string. Two fields must be put together in a single object: `JSON.stringify({ userID, name })`

Comment: suppose in my post function, i want to either return 1 or 2 depending on some condition...  how to get that value in my html file .. and also i want my execution to stop till i get this call completed .. i.e i get either of 1 or 2 .. and then execute rest of it .. how to do that ?